# Find the latest / earliest day in Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a `m2` RDD consisting of

```
case class Medication(patientID: String, date: Date, medicine: String)
```

and I need to find the first and the last day. I tried

```
val latest_date_m2  = m2.maxBy(_.date).date
```

I got:

```
No implicit Ordering defined for java.sql.Date.
[error]       val latest_date_m2 = m2.maxBy(_.date).date
```

It looks like Scala "does not know" how to compare the dates. I think, I need replace `maxBy` by a different function, but I cannot find this one.

Comment: can you specify the format of your date? Is it type of Date of String or TimeStamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just provide the `Ordering`

```
import scala.math.Ordering

object SQLDateOrdering extends Ordering[java.sql.Date] {
  def compare(a: java.sql.Date, b: java.sql.Date) = a compareTo b
}

m2.maxBy(_.date)(SQLDateOrdering)
```

though it is worth noting that `m2` cannot be `RDD` as `RDD` has no `maxBy` method (it is likely a Seq). If it was `RDD` you'd need

```
object MedicationDateOrdering extends Ordering[Medication] {
  def compare(a: Medication, b: Medication) = a.date compareTo b.date
}
```

and `max`

```
m2.max()(MedicationDateOrdering)
```